# Android Studio auto importing wrong Context class

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, android-studio-2.3, auto-import

Android studio has been auto importing `io.realm.internal.Context` instead of `android.content.Context` and its getting very annoying.  I have to highlight and manually type the import statement because Android Studio continues to auto import the wrong class.  Is there any way to tell the IDE to not auto import certain packages? I *never* use the Realm context class, and whenever I reference Context for the first time it *always* erroneously imports that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to tell the IDE to not auto import certain packages. Please refer following steps:

In Android Studio go to

1. Settings>Editor>General>Auto Import
2. In the dialog box that opens, type the name of the class or a whole package to be excluded, and click OK.
   Use new (Alt+Insert) and delete (Alt+Delete) to manage the list of classes and packages that IntelliJ IDEA shouldn't place to the suggestion list.
3. Apply changes and close Settings/Preferences dialog.

This will surely help :-)